# How to set the status of Keywords?

Tags: robotframework

I run a keyword based from another one.

```
My Keyword 1
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    ${keyword}      ${args}
    ${statusTestCase}=    Run Keyword If    ${status} is True
    ...    Set Variable    Passed
    ...    ELSE
    ...    Set Variable    Failed
```

If `${status}` is not `True`, then I put `Failed` in my custom report. However the log and report are Passed (so in green) (because `Run Keyword And Return Status` and `My Keyword 1`) have been executed without error.

How to set the log/report/keywords as Failed (so in red) if there is at least one failed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> How to set the log/report/keywords as Failed (so in red) if there is at least one failed ?

The keyword needs to throw an exception. You can do that by calling the [Fail](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fail) keyword from the BuiltIn library:

```
Run Keyword If  ${status} is False
...  Fail  A custom message
```